# Find a first order DE satisfied by the Wronskian

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the homogenous linear DE $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$. Suppose that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions on $[a,b]$. Define $W(x)=y_1(x)y_2'(x)-y_1'(x)y_2(x)$.

Find a first order DE satisfied by W and solve it.

---

I'm a bit confused by the question, am I supposed to find an expression for $y$ that reduces the DE to $W$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case $y_1,y_2$ are two solutions to $y''+py'+qy=0$, calculate $$W'=y_1'y_2'+y_1y_2''-y_1'y_2'-y_1''y_2=y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2$$ then 
$$\frac{W'}{W}=\frac{y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2}{y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2}$$
$$=\frac{y_1(-py_2'-qy_2)-y_2(-py_1'-qy_1)}{y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2}$$
$$=\frac{-py_1y_2'-qy_1y_2+qy_1y_2+py_2y_1'}{y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2}=-p$$
so we have the first order ODE $W'=pW$, whcih you can solve for some exponential solution which I leave to you :)

Comment: Wow, thanks... it makes sense now.

Comment: no worries :) was  an ambiguous question to be fair